# Problema com tratamento de datas numa aplicação ACCESS/VBA com banco SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, datetime, microsoft-access

Precisei migrar o banco de uma aplicação feita em vba utilizando o access. O banco era nativo do access e passei para SQL Server.

No access, como é tudo nativo tudo funcionava perfeitamente, porém na migração um problema que está me dando muita dor de cabeça é a conversão de datas.

O access exibe e salva os registros no formato dd/mm/yyyy

```
25/06/1987
```

O SQL Server no entanto possui o formato yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss

```
1987-06-25 00:00:00
```

Com algumas mudanças de configuração de formato default de datas(no SQL Server) obtive sucesso apenas na inserção de dados. Porém não consegui de forma alguma nas consultas retornar a data no formato dd/mm/yyyy.

Atualmente estou tendo que preparar a aplicação sempre antes de inserir, formatando as datas para o formato SQL Server, bem como nas consultas também formatando a data de volta para o formato Access.

Além de não ser uma solução "bonita" não consegui sanar todos os bugs que isso causa no sistema. Por vezes não tenho o controle absoluto do que o access quer salvar ou retornar do banco e as datas nos campos ficam no formato errado.

Enfim. A questão é:

**Existe alguma forma de configurar as datas do SQL Server para receberem e retornarem dados no formato dd/mm/yyyy?**

**Ou então existe alguma solução para isso no próprio access que me poupe o trabalho de tratar todas as consultas?**

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/5202d93b-eacb-4dfd-bd76-0c069b47f254/mudar-formato-data-para-pt?forum=infrageral

Comment: https://adrianobrandaodba.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/alterar-o-formato-de-data-do-sql-server/

Comment: Creio que se buscar somente a data sem a hora o Access já vai ler da forma como precisa. Faça um teste ai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muitas pesquisas na internet e nada esclarecedor acabei chegando a um post num fórum que elucidou a questão.

Ao olhar o design de uma das tabelas ODBC do sql server dentro do access, reparei que os campos de data estavam setados como texto curto.

Ao trazer as tabelas do sql server através do odbc wizard do access ele entendeu que os campos datetime2(0) eram texto curto, ao invés de data, e por isso não tratava isso corretamente na aplicação.

Para corrigir isso tive que me concluir três ações:
- Garantir que todas as tabelas tenham uma primary key.
- Garantir que todos os campos Bit tenham um valor default
- Trocar todas os campos de data para o tipo "datetime"

Após seguir esses passos e atualizar as tabelas vinculadas, o access leu corretamente os campos como sendo de data, ao invés de texto curto e todas as minhas requisições puderam ser efetuadas sem necessidade de formatação de datas.

OBS: Meu banco SQL Server foi migrado do Access através de uma ferramenta de migração e definiu todos os campos de data como datetime2(0).